# Read/Parse a resx file to identify

Tags: .net, resx

I'm trying to read or parse an XML resource (.resx) file (something similar to the snippet below), and identify how many of the  nodes have the  node in them. My options are either using python or a .Net console app.

```
  <data name="Carrier1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Carrier1Val</value>
    <comment>Parameter to display Carrier 1</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="Carrier2" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Carrier2Val</value> 
    <comment>Parameter to display Carrier 2</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="Employee1" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Employee1Val</value>
  </data>
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the above XML sample? And what does "the nodes have the node in them" mean? In XML, text is also a `node`

Comment: @Eldar, I think primarily my objective is to get some stats on this resource file. Say which <data> has comment in them and which of them don't. In my above example, I would likely to see two of the data has comments in them and one of them don't. If I can get to this, I'll leverage them to identify what percentage of my resx file doesn't have any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq2Xml` like below :

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = @"
<root>
 <data name=""Carrier1"" xml:space=""preserve"">
    <value>Carrier1Val</value>
    <comment>Parameter to display Carrier 1</comment>
  </data>
  <data name=""Carrier2"" xml:space=""preserve"">
    <value>Carrier2Val</value> 
    <comment>Parameter to display Carrier 2</comment>
  </data>
  <data name=""Employee1"" xml:space=""preserve"">
    <value>Employee1Val</value>
  </data>
</root>";
var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
var result = doc.Elements("data").Where(r => r.Element("comment") is not null).Count();
// result = 2
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NfhLtT)

Comment: Perfect @Eldar ! Didn't realize there's something as easy as this Linq2XML. Thanks a lot!